# HTMLElement.style.borderColor is not providing the correct value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, colors

```js
function goToSlide3(){
    if(advanced.style.borderColor==="#FF00B8" ||      
       pro.style.borderColor==="#483EFF" || 
       arcade.style.borderColor==="#FF8A00") {
       
       // Code here
    }
}
```

I'm trying that if the `pro.style.borderColor === "#FF00B8"` or `arcade.style.borderColor === "#FF8A00"` then `goToNextSide` but JavaScript doesn't recognize the hexadecimal color value. It recognizes the HTML color name. For example, `arcade.style.borderColor === "red"` then it accepts it.

Comment: Hello. Have you tried adding console.log(pro.style.borderColor)  to see what value is expected?

Comment: You are comparing strings, not colors

Comment: Some browsers return colors in RGB format not HEX

Comment: I'm here to review this post, not answer it... but I think I can help you out. Using `HTMLElement.style` will only provide inline styles. It will not provide the computed value. [This StackOverflow answer might be what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336002/how-to-get-computed-background-color-style-inherited-from-parent-element).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

i think in your case u can use [`window.getComputedStyle(<dom element>)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

It return will return, not a HEX value of color, but always RGB (like `rgb(255,255,255)`) and u can easly converted it HEX