# CSS make an absolutely positioned HTML element opaque without setting background color

Tags: html, css, popover

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.globalpopup {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  background: inherit;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <table class="globalpopup"><tr><td><span>!!</span></td></tr>
 </table>
 <div>This is a document. There's a ton of stuff here.
</body>
</html>
```

The table background is transparent even though the background of the text within it (the span tag) is opaque.

How do I make the table opaque in entirety without setting a background color? There are *no* set colors anywhere; browser defaults are used. If you think you know what the browser defaults are, then you don't.

Copying the background color from body with javascript didn't help. document.body.style.backgroundColor is the empty string.

Somebody asked a similar question awhile back and got the answer of `background: inherit`. This case is different somehow and `backgorund: inherit` doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question to improve its clarity. I don't understand "the text within it is opaque" -- are you talking about the (foreground) text itself or the background? The only way to make the table opaque is to set a background color. Why do you not want to do that? You can [set the body background](https://dev.to/bcalou/why-you-should-always-set-a-background-color-2gb1) to the same color as your table background if you don't trust browser defaults.

Comment: you can also get computed background color see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336002/how-to-get-computed-background-color-style-inherited-from-parent-element)

Comment: @BrettDonald: Because it's better to not set any colors at all and just inherit the browser defaults. I am one of the users with inverted defaults. Once I set one color it's a spreading disease through the whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root color is accessible trough the [Canvas](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#valdef-color-canvas) color value:

```css
.globalpopup {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  background: Canvas;
}
```

```html
<table class="globalpopup"><tr><td><span>!!</span></td></tr></table>
<div>This is a document. There's a ton of stuff here.
```

And if one wants to access it through JS, then they can append an element with that color value set somewhere and grab the computed value:

```js
const getCanvasColor = () => {
  const tester = document.createElement("span");
  tester.style.color = "Canvas";
  document.body.append(tester);
  const computed = getComputedStyle(tester).color;
  tester.remove();
  return computed;
}
console.log(getCanvasColor());
```

Comment: Ok wow. It is indeed that trivial; just beyond a Google search because of runaway blogs with the same repeating poor advise including my biggest bane of just set the background color and not the foreground.